# ReportMissingAttributeIssue

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I keep getting this error message reportmissingattributrissue as shown in vs code. I don't understand why? But the code works fine and perfect without any errors while running. please help me resolve this.

I tried some YouTube videos and couldn't find any issue as I'm a beginner.